# Enable System.Form.Timer from Backgroundworker

Tags: c#, timer, backgroundworker

Friends i have this problem,hope some body to help me,
I have Timer.Tick event and Backgroundworker_dowork event,what i wanted to do is enable timer tick event from background worker,can any one tell me how to do this?
 private void ManualController()
        {

```
        if (TabControl1.SelectedTab == tabPage1 && Globs.DeltaP != 0)
        {
            if (checkBox6.Checked == true && Globs.DeltaP > 0)
            {
                do
                {

                    Globs.voltage += 0.1;

                    data_logger.WriteString("SOURce:VOLTage" + " " + (Globs.voltage.ToString().Replace(",", ".")) + ",(@104)", true);

                }
                while (Globs.DeltaP == Globs.tolerance);


            }

            if (checkBox6.Checked == true && Globs.DeltaP < 0)
            {

                do
                {
                    Globs.voltage -= 0.1;

                    data_logger.WriteString("SOURce:VOLTage" + " " + (Globs.voltage.ToString().Replace(",", ".")) + ",(@104)", true);

                }
                while (Globs.DeltaP == (-1) * Globs.tolerance);



            }

            timer3.Enabled = true;
            //  timer4.Start();


        }
    }
```

this methode call from background worker ,backgroundworker calling from timer tick event for every second,but here i cant able to enable timer3 from backgroundworker3

Comment: this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => { timer3.Enabled = true; }));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure if this is the correct answer, but try enabling the timer on the main form, not from the backgroundworker.

Try:

```
 this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => { timer3.Enabled = true; }));
```

Or

```
 this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() { timer3.Enabled = true; });
```

(P.S. Both lines do the same)

Comment: Hi Brian  Thanks for ur responce,but i should enable it in backwrk because with every second i have to check wether the value is equal to zero r not

Comment: Tarakaram, you should run this code in your backgroundworker. It will start the timer from the main form. 
P.S. This is kinda unknown stuff to me, just trying to give some ideas :)

Comment: Alrighty, great. So the thing that causes it to fail is that you cannot assign controls that are made in another thread directly. You'll probably get a 'Cross-Thread operation is not valid' message. This way you let the main form run the delegate/lambda which enables the timer.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this code can help you

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    // init worker
    worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
}

void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    // init worker
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: but Timer is System.form.timer not System.timers.timer